# What is the "structure" of the Solar System while traveling through Space?

Tags: solar-system

[image]

On the Image above, the arrows pointing upwards depict Solar System's travel direction.
 The arrows pointing to the right show its own direction of rotation and the direction of the planets within it revolving around the Sun.
The big circles are the Sun and the stripes are its differential rotation. 
Is any of the two examples above correct?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34534/16685

Comment: i tried to understand but is way to advanced for me. If you could draw a picture, it would be awesome!

Comment: I'm not sure if the other one is a duplicate,  but I think the answer you want is that the solar system rotates around an axis that is tilted 63 degrees from the plane of the galaxy.

Comment: You can view an animation of the true motion of the Solar System at https://ecliptiqc.ca/vrai.php (the page is in French, but the animation is self-explanatory).

Comment: That is great. Thank you Pierre. I now understand that Sun's differential rotation has the  same direction as the the revolution of the planets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first image is closer.  The planets orbit roughly in a plane that aligns with the equator of the sun.

The rotation of the planets is varied,  Jupiter rotates in the same plane as the sun. The Earth in inclined by 23 degrees to this plane, and Uranus is tiped sideways at 98 degrees. Venus rotates very slowly backwards, tilted 180 degrees.

The solar system then moves relative to the centre of the galaxy in a direction that included by about 60 degrees to this plane.

Comment: thank you James. By saying roughly in a plane that aligns with the equator of the Sun, i get the understanding that there is some "dragging" between the Sun and the planets. Is that a viable point of view?

Comment: No dragging,  Just gravity

Comment: that's right. Damn it, I need a break from sciences. Shutting down my brain. Good luck!